# What do you mean by Memoryless property of Exponential distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability

I know memorylessness defines "the next state depends only on the current state and not on the sequence of events that preceded it". However, if some one could explain me how exponential distribution has this property.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Math Stack Exchange; it has no connection to programming.

Answer (score 2):

THe Exponential distribution is called memoryless because the conditional distribution is the same as the unconditional distribution.

Consider the following example: The cdf of X is denoted by $f(x, \lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} & x \ge 0 $  ( I have not figured out how to write LaTex in Stackexchange, I think I wrote LaTex in Math Stackexchange in the same way I did here but it displays differently - maybe you can kindly edit it?)  You want to know the probability that an event happens after time t. The integral from t to infinity is: $ P(X > t) = e^(-\lambda t) $. Now, the conditional probability of the event happening after time t, given that it did not happen unit time k is again: $ P(Y > t | X > k)  =  e^(-\lambda t) $. Hence, the distribution is called memoryless.

Answer (score 1):

Via http://www.statlect.com/ucdexp1.htm, a simple explanation with the exponential distribution framed as time to event (**X**):

> **X** is the time we need to wait before a certain event occurs. The Memoryless property says that the probability that the event happens during a time interval of length  **y** is independent of how much time has already elapsed **x** without the event happening.